# Parsing a malformed(?) json file with Jackson Json

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a [JSON file](https://mtgjson.com/api/v5/AllPrintings.json) from [MTG JSON](https://mtgjson.com/downloads/all-files/) that is setup like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "10E": {
      ...
    }
    "2ED": {
      ...
    }
    "3ED": {
      ...
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Each of the objects under `data` is of type [`Set`](https://mtgjson.com/data-models/set/), but they're not labeled as `Set`, instead they're labeled like you see above -- with a three letter set-code.

I know I can do something like this:

```
public class Data {
  @JsonProperty("10E")
  Set x10E;
  
  @JsonProperty("2ED")
  Set x2ED;
}
```

but I don't want to have to hardcode each set by name. Instead, I'd like to have an array or list of sets. Something like this, where Jackson ignores the label and treats it like an array (or any other list) of Set Objects.

```
public class Data {
  Set[] sets;
}
```

Is there a way to get Jackson JSON to make that conversion?  My current main method looks like this:

```
public class AllPrintings {
  Data data;
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    byte[] jsonData = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("stage/AllPrintings.json"));
    JsonParser parser = new ObjectMapper().readTree(jsonData).traverse();
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    parser.nextToken();
    om.setVisibility(VisibilityChecker.Std.defaultInstance().withFieldVisibility(Visibility.ANY));
    AllPrintings allPrintings = om.readValue(parser, AllPrintings.class);
  }
}
```

Comment: Just don't declare any of those fields in `Data` and then follow this approach: [Jackson deserialize extra fields as map](//stackoverflow.com/q/39156293)

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you. If you make it an answer I can accept and upvote.

Comment: Feel free to write your own answer with the updated code. That would be more helpful for future readers, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As recommended by @Tom in the comments, I can use the annotation `@JsonAnySetter` to dump any undefined fields into a Map:

```
public class Data {
  Map<String, Set> sets = new HashMap<>();
  
  @JsonAnySetter
  public void setOtherField(String name, Set value) {
    sets.put(name, value);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need even this. You didn't show the structure of each value, but just deserializing directly to `Map<String, whatever> data` should work.

Comment: How? It would be a Map<String, Set>.  I agree that's the goal. The answer above works well. Is there a better way?

Comment: First, you should avoid the specific name `Set` (because it's a standard Java type) and use something like `MtgSet`. That said, you don't need `@JsonAnySetter` if _the entire contents_ of `data` is a map; you just say `Map<String, MtgSet> data` and are done. `@JsonAnySetter` is needed only when you have a mix of ordinary properties and dynamic properties. (FWIW, if as it appears this is JSON:API, you might consider using tools specifically designed to assist with consuming it.)

Comment: > "That said, you don't need @JsonAnySetter if the entire contents of data is a map; you just say Map<String, MtgSet> data and are done" -- I tried that before and again now, it doesn't work.

Comment: Now that I understand a bit better, I'll try a complete answer.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Regarding "Set", OP has linked that in the question, it is part of a library, so OP can't change the name.

Comment: @Tom It's just the name used in the API definition. He doesn't actually have a Java library that bakes the names in.

Comment: He's right about the name, but I don't think it needs much focus. I was rapid prototyping and it was easy to just match the specs exactly. Ctrl + shift + r is a click away in eclipse.  It was 50/50 this code was going in the bin.

Answer (score 1):

To start, `Set` is the name of [a standard built-in Java type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), so I'll use `MtgSet` to avoid confusion from using an existing name.

It looks like you may be parsing [JSON:API](https://jsonapi.org/format/), in which case a library that handles its structure specifically might be helpful. However, I'll show how to do it in just plain Jackson.

To start, we'll define a wrapper class to match your root JSON:

```java
class AllPrintings {
  Map<String, MtgSet> data;
}
```

Your Jackson invocations are a little overcomplicated, and we can simplify.

```java
var is = new FileInputStream("stage/AllPrintings.json"); // just open it directly
Map<String, MtgSet> sets = new ObjectMapper()
  .readValue(is, AllPrintings.class) // no need to explicitly mess with parser instances
  .data; // pull the wrapped value out of the wrapper class
is.close();
```